# MATLAB: Simple function that takes in a matrix as an argument

Tags: matlab

I have the following simple function that returns the (1,1) element in MATLAB:

```
function out = blah(A)
    out = A(1,1);
end
%% test
A = [1 2; 3 4];

out = blah(A);
```

However, the output I get is:

```
Undefined function 'blah' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

What gives?

Comment: Are you running this from the command line? In MATLAB, functions can only be defined in a `.m` file. As an alternative, you could use an anonymous function, `blah =@(A) A(1,1);` from the command window to do the same job.

Comment: I ran the lines after "%% test" by pressing ctrl+enter...

Comment: You should put blah in blah.m and test in command window in the folder with blah.m.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't like you mixing function definitions with scripts. Every function you write should have its own `.m` file, with the title of the file being the same as the function (`blah.m` for function `blah`). Any scripts or code you run from the command line will then have access to these functions as long as they are in the current folder.